# How do I turn input type radio into select with options?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select

I have this input type radio:

```
<div *ngFor="let status of statuses; let i = index">
    <input (click)="editStatus(order, status)" type="radio" [checked]="order.status == status" 
         name="status" [value]="status">{{orderStatuses[status]}}
</div>
```

I turned it into this select:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let status of statuses; let i = index" name="status" [value]="status.value"
        [selected]="order.status == status" (change)="editStatus(order, status)">
        {{orderStatuses[status]}}
    </option>
</select>
```

But after that, function "editStatus(order, status)" stopped working - not doing anything. I think it's because it doesn't get the correct "status" in the parameter. How to fix it?

ts file:

```
order: Order;
statuses = Object.keys(OrderStatus);
orderStatuses = OrderStatus;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribe = this.route.params.pipe(
      map(({ id }) => id),
      switchMap((id: string) => this.orderService.getOrderById(id)))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.order = res;
      });
  }
editStatus(order, status) {
    this.orderEdited = { order, status };
    this.orderService.editStatus(this.orderEdited).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Order interface and enum OrderStatus:

```
export interface Order {
  sum: number;
  items: {};
  status: string;
}

export enum OrderStatus {
  order_placed = 'placed',
  order_confirmed = 'confirmed',
  order_shipped = 'shipped',
  order_completed = 'completed',
  order_canceled = 'canceled',
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place change event on select element.

```
<select (change)="editStatus($event.target.value,order)">
    <option *ngFor="let status of statuses; let i = index" name="status" [value]="status.value"
        [selected]="order.status == status" >
        {{orderStatuses[status]}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: With this solution, status takes undefined value :(

Comment: You cant access ngFor value outsite options tag

Comment: So how to solve it? When I move "(change)" inside, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Why you want to pass staus property to change event? If you are trying to get selected value then you can use $event object to get selected value

Comment: I want get selected value, so how to use $event object to do it? When I use $event.target.value I get undefined value.

Comment: make sure you passing $event object as first argument ?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing $event object as first argument and still undefined.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ojvpd?file=src/app/app.component.html it's working fine in the stackblitz

Comment: You're right. It should work. I have almost the same as you but I don't know why it doesn't work :/ I keep getting undefine value. But thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Check wheather you assiging proper value attribute==> [value]="status.value"

Comment: Exactly! I just checked this and that was the problem! I change [value]="status.value" to [value]="status", and now everything work fine :) Thank you very much <3